# Bash - Check if the string starts with a predefined string (substring)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a variable `$projectName` how can i check if it starts with this string 'testProject'

Comment: so glad nobody marked this question "repeated question" since only here could find the answer!

Answer (score 17):

You can use this check in BASH:

```
[[ "$projectName" == "testProject"* ]]
```

Comment: Finally something that worked!

Answer (score 11):

You can for example use:

```
[[ "$projectName" =~ ^testProject ]] && echo "yes"
                     ^
                     beginning of line
```

#### Test

```
$ var="hello"
$ [[ "$var" =~ ^he ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
$ var="ahello"
$ [[ "$var" =~ ^he ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Comment: The 2nd example 
$ var="ahello"
$ [[ "$var" =~ ^he ]] && echo "yes"
Should return 'no' because it's not starting with 'he'

Comment: @user3502786 well it wasn't returning anything because `||` was not defined. I just did for better understanding.